# c:when test expression returning false

Tags: jsp, jstl, percentage

`<c:when test="{(a/b)*100 < 1}"> <td> <1% </td>
</c:when>`

the above condition always returning false no matter what values I pass..

tried with lt 
tried to use fn:substringBefore and compared with 0...

None of them work. Any idea why?

tried with lt instead of <
tried to use fn:substringBefore and compared with 0...

None of them work. Any idea why?

I expected to return the condition as true when passed a=2 and b=954 something like this..

Comment: The syntax for EL expressions is `${  expression here }`.

Comment: Sorry.. I did include $ symbol also..forgot to include.

Comment: <c:when test="${(a/b)*100 < 1}"> <td> <1% </td>
</c:when>. Forgot to include $ in the original post. My issue not resolved yet.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you use tag <c:when> without <c:choose> ?